# Duplicate Python Source Code Window in Emacs python-mode

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, python-mode

I am using Emacs 27 with Evil mode to write python code.

Every time I do M-x py-execute-buffer, the python source code was duplicated in a new window while the python shell runs. So Emacs would end up with three zones on the screen, one for the python shell with the results of the run, two with identical source code in them.

Is there a way to avoid the additional source code buffer?

Thanks a lot.

kz